# Full join 3 tables in SAS : Sent, open, complain

Tags: sql, join, sas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW9lY.png)I have attached the results I am expecting to get and this is the code(this code works perfectly fine when I am only joining two tables):

```
  **proc sql;
  create table result_test as
  select bounce.bouncedate,
  open.openflag,
  open.opendate,
  complain.complainflag,
  complain.complaindate,
    coalesce (sent.JobId, open.JobId, bounce.JobId, complain.JobID) as JobId
  , coalesce (sent.EmailAddress, open.EmailAddress, bounce.EmailAddress, complain.EmailAddress) as EmailAddress
  , case 
      when bounce.JobID is null or bounce.EmailAddress is null then '0'
      else bounce.bounceflag
    end as bounceflag
    ,case when open.JobID is null or open.EmailAddress is null then '0'
    else open.openflag end as openflag,
    case when complain.JobID is null or complain.EmailAddress is null then'0'
    else complain.complainflag
    end as complainflag
  from
    sent
  full join 
    bounce
  on
    sent.JobId = bounce.JobId AND
    sent.EmailAddress = bounce.EmailAddress
    full join 
    open on
    sent.JobId = open.JobId AND
    sent.EmailAddress = open.EmailAddress
    full join 
    complain on 
    sent.JobID= complain.JobID AND 
    sent.EmailAddress= complain.EmailAddress
  ;**
```

However here's one example of what I got while checking on the results... There's something wrong so the same complain appeared twice, as I highlighted complaindate there are two 8:07:54 AM. It should only include one, I can't just distinct it because one of the open record would be deleted too.

Comment: What's the difference between images? Unclear what are your desired results.

Comment: Again: Use text, not links/images & give a [mre] that incudes cut & paste & runnable code that is working code extended to non-working saying what you expected instead & why. Don't ask us to debug your code for you.

Comment: @Parfait Hello, didnt notice that i have uploaded  two same images. I have updated the image which has the information of 3 tables and the desired results. The problem I am having here is: when I joined 2 tables, perfect, however when it came to 3, the results are giving me extra records...

Comment: Duplicate rows indicates either data errors (replicate entries) with respect to the processing model or incomplete modeling (too broad join criteria) of the actual data. I guess you might need to join to a correlated sub-select that reduces multiple rows to a single keyed row via aggregation, or has single row result set according to the proper business rule.  Follow @philipxy advice about reproducible example.  I recommend stepping back and rebuild the problem with generic 'non-domain' column names such as key1, x, y, date1, date2, date3 and work on the generic problem first.

Answer (score 0):

Since your desired results is not a full outer join, consider a different approach. For this particular use case, two `LEFT JOIN`s can work. However, this is not generalizable but must be tailored for additional joined tables such as `bounce` (not included in desired results). Below will return missing values or `NULL` instead of zeros. Otherwise run `COALSECE`.

```sql
SELECT s.JobId, s.Email
       , o.DateOpen, o.OpenFlag
       , c.DateComplain, c.ComplainFlag
FROM sent s
LEFT JOIN open o
  ON  s.JobID = o.JobId
  AND s.Email = o.Email
  
LEFT JOIN complain c
  ON  o.JobID = c.JobId
  AND o.Email = c.Email
  AND o.DateOpen = c.DateComplain
```

<kbd>[**dbfiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tH6cDG29ttVvbCEJH3gkvD/0)</kbd> *(using SQLite dialect but should conform to SAS `proc sql`)*